# load new frame/window while clicking the button with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i have been making a tkinter program in which i have to load new frame/window while clicking the button

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import tkinter.messagebox as tm

t=Tk()
t.title('Gym Management')
t["bg"]="black"

#declaration of frame
top=Frame(t)
top.grid(row=0,columnspan=2)
left=Frame(t)
left.grid(row=1,column=0)
right=Frame(t,bg="black")
right.grid(row=1,column=1)

#top frame
l1=Label(top,text="Silver`s Gym",fg="yellow",bg="black",font="impact 50 bold",pady=30)
l1.grid(sticky=E)

#left frame
img1=PhotoImage(file="1.png")
i1=Label(left,image=img1,padx=10)
i1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)

#right frame
l2=Label(right,text="USERNAME",fg="white",bg="black",padx=10,width=10)
l2.grid(row=0,column=0)
l3=Label(right,text="PASSWORD",fg="white",bg="black",padx=10,width=10)
l3.grid(row=1,column=0)
e2=Entry(right)
e2.grid(row=0,column=1)
e3=Entry(right,show="*")
e3.grid(row=1,column=1)
checkbox = Checkbutton(right, text="Keep me logged in",fg="white",bg="black")
checkbox.grid(columnspan=2)

# defining login button
def login_btn_clickked():
        enter code here`#print("Clicked")
        username = e2.get()
        password = e3.get()

        #print(username, password)

        if username == "john" and password == "password":
            tm.showinfo("Login info", "Welcome John")
        else:
            tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username")
#defining signup button
def sugnup_btn_clickked():
    filename = 'test.py'
    os.system(filename) #Open file [Same as Right-click Open]
    os.system('notepad '+filename)

logbtn = Button(right, text="Login", command = login_btn_clickked,width=15,padx=2)
logbtn.grid(row=3,column=0)
signup = Button(right, text="sign up", command = sugnup_btn_clickked,width=15,padx=2)
signup.grid(row=3,column=1)
t.mainloop()
```

what should i add to do it?
i haven`t learn the concept of tk so please explain it with the t the way i have done

Comment: You want to load a new frame or a new window? Describe what your code is supposed to do, ie what the user interaction will be like.

Answer (score 3):

Please be very, **very** careful when using the word *frame* and the word *window* when talking about tkinter.

They are so very, **very** distinct from each other.

`Frame` widgets in tkinter are essentially "boxes" which you put things in. They can be used to separate different widgets into their own containers in a window similar (although not identical) to the way in which `div`s work in HTML.

There are two distinct types of "window" in tkinter `Tk()` windows and `Toplevel` widgets.

The key difference is that **you shouldn't ever have more than one `Tk()` window** [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37503535/4528269) explains why this is the case. `Toplevel` widgets on the other hand can be used whenever and wherever you want and should be used as "extra windows" whenever your application needs to have more than one window.

The below script shows how you can use buttons to create both `Frame`s and `Toplevel`s where the new `Frame` widgets are just empty red squares and the new `Toplevel` widgets are just empty windows

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def frame():
    Frame(root, bg="red", width=100, height=100).pack(padx=5, pady=5)

def window():
    Toplevel(root)

framebutton = Button(root, text="Frame", command=frame)
framewindow = Button(root, text="Window", command=window)

framebutton.pack()
framewindow.pack()

root.mainloop()
```