# How to set a color for a Combobox in all windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, combobox, themes

I was working on a GUI using TKinter (in Python 3). When I finished it, I wanted to set a color to all the widgets. I didn't have any problem changing the color of Text and Button widgets, I just used the `bg` option:

```
t = Text(master, wrap = WORD, bg = '#ffffb3')
```

Then, I tried to set the color of `ttk.Combobox` widgets, I noticed they don't have this option, so I finally changed their color using themes, as explained in this post: [How to set the background color of a ttk.Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912250/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-a-ttk-combobox). But I had a problem applying the theme to all the windows. As you'll see if you try the following code, the theme only applies to the Combobox in the first window, but not to the Combobox in the window that is created when you press the button:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

r = Tk()

def callback():
    r2 = Tk()

    c2 = ttk.Combobox(r2)
    c2.pack()

b = Button(r, text = 'Open', command = callback)
b.pack()

combostyle = ttk.Style()
combostyle.theme_create('combostyle', parent = 'alt', settings = {'TCombobox':{'configure':
    {'fieldbackground': '#ffff99', 'background': '#ffcc66'}}})
combostyle.theme_use('combostyle')

c = ttk.Combobox(r)
c.pack()

r.mainloop()
```

That's the first time I use themes in TKinter, so forgive me if I've made a stupid mistake. I've searched through the Internet and didn't find any solution. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having more than one instance of `Tk` in a program is a big no. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502942/tkinter-creating-multiple-windows-use-new-tk-instance-or-toplevel-or-frame#37503535). Quoting it here :

> Every tkinter program needs exactly one instance of Tk. Tkinter is a wrapper around an embedded tcl interpreter. Each instance of Tk gets its own copy of the interpreter, so two Tk instances have two different namespaces.
>
> If you need multiple windows, create one instance of Tk and then additional windows should be instances of Toplevel.

So, if you need multiple windows, use a `Toplevel`. Here is an example.

P.S. For styling a `ttk` widget, read the [docs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html). It can be done easily using `.configure()` of `ttk.Style()`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

r = tk.Tk()

def callback():
    r2 = tk.Toplevel()

    c2 = ttk.Combobox(r2, style='ARD.TCombobox')
    c2.pack()

b = tk.Button(r, text = 'Open', command = callback)
b.pack()

combostyle = ttk.Style()
combostyle.configure('ARD.TCombobox', background="#ffcc66", fieldbackground="#ffff99")

c = ttk.Combobox(style='ARD.TCombobox')
c.pack()

r.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This solves my problem. I didn't know I couldn't have more than an instance of Tk.